# Reusing an Event Hub stream for multiple queries in Azure Data Bricks

Tags: databricks, azure-eventhub, azure-databricks

In Azure Databricks Structured Streaming (scala notebook, connected to Azure IoT Hub) I am opening a stream on the Event Hub compatible endpoint of Azure IoT Hub.  Then I parse the incoming stream, based on the structured schema and I create 3 queries (groupBy) on the same stream.
Most of the times (not always, it seems) I get an exception on one of the display queries around an epoch value on the partition.  (see below)
I am using a dedicated consumer group on which no other application is reading.  So, I would guess that opening 1 stream and having multiple streaming queries against it would be supported?
Any suggestions, any explanations or ideas to solve this?  (I would like to avoid having to create 3 consumer groups and defining the stream 3 times again)

Exception example:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 3 in stage 1064.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   3.3 in stage 1064.0 (TID 24790, 10.139.64.10, executor 7): java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:
>   com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.ReceiverDisconnectedException: New
>   receiver with higher epoch of '0' is created hence current receiver
>   with epoch '0' is getting disconnected. If you are recreating the
>   receiver, make sure a higher epoch is used. TrackingId:xxxx,
>   SystemTracker:iothub-name|databricks-db,
>   Timestamp:2019-02-18T15:25:19, errorContext[NS: yyy, PATH:
>   savanh-traffic-camera2/ConsumerGroups/databricks-db/Partitions/3,
>   REFERENCE_ID: a0e445_7319_G2_1550503505013, PREFETCH_COUNT: 500,
>   LINK_CREDIT: 500, PREFETCH_Q_LEN: 0]

This is my code: (cleaned up)

```
// Define schema and create incoming camera eventstream
val cameraEventSchema = new StructType()
    .add("TrajectId", StringType)
    .add("EventTime", StringType)
    .add("Country", StringType)
    .add("Make", StringType)

val iotHubParameters =
    EventHubsConf(cameraHubConnectionString)
    .setConsumerGroup("databricks-db")
    .setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromEndOfStream)

val incomingStream = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(iotHubParameters.toMap).load()

// Define parsing query selecting the required properties from the incoming telemetry data
val cameraMessages =
    incomingStream
    .withColumn("Offset", $"offset".cast(LongType))
    .withColumn("Time (readable)", $"enqueuedTime".cast(TimestampType))
    .withColumn("Timestamp", $"enqueuedTime".cast(LongType))
    .withColumn("Body", $"body".cast(StringType))
    // Select the event hub fields so we can work with them
    .select("Offset", "Time (readable)", "Timestamp", "Body")
    // Parse the "Body" column as a JSON Schema which we defined above
    .select(from_json($"Body", cameraEventSchema) as "cameraevents")
    // Now select the values from our JSON Structure and cast them manually to avoid problems
    .select(
        $"cameraevents.TrajectId".cast("string").alias("TrajectId"),
        $"cameraevents.EventTime".cast("timestamp").alias("EventTime"), 
        $"cameraevents.Country".cast("string").alias("Country"), 
        $"cameraevents.Make".cast("string").alias("Make") 
    )
    .withWatermark("EventTime", "10 seconds")

val groupedDataFrame = 
  cameraMessages 
      .groupBy(window($"EventTime", "5 seconds") as 'window)
      .agg(count("*") as 'count)
      .select($"window".getField("start") as 'window, $"count")
display(groupedDataFrame)

val makeDataFrame = 
  cameraMessages 
      .groupBy("Make")
      .agg(count("*") as 'count)
      .sort($"count".desc)

display(makeDataFrame)

val countryDataFrame = 
  cameraMessages 
      .groupBy("Country")
      .agg(count("*") as 'count)
      .sort($"count".desc)

display(countryDataFrame)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the stream data into a table or a file location, then you can run the multiple queries on that table or file, all are running in real time.
For a file, you need to specify the schema while extracting the data into a data frame, so it's a good practice to write the stream data into a table.

```
cameraMessages.writeStream
 .format("delta") 
 .outputMode("append")
 .option("checkpointLocation","/data/events/_checkpoints/data_file")
 .table("events")
```

Now you can execute your queries on the table 'events'. 
And for the data frame -

```
cameraMessages = spark.readStream.table("events")
```

I have faced the same issue while using EventHub, and the above trick is work for me.

for using a file instead of table

```
//Write/Append streaming data to file
cameraMessages.writeStream
  .format("parquet")
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/FileStore/StreamCheckPoint.parquet")
  .option("path","/FileStore/StreamData")
  .start()
//Read data from the file, we need to specify the schema for it
val Schema = (
 new StructType()
    .add(StructField("TrajectId", StringType))
    .add(StructField("EventTime", TimestampType))
    .add(StructField("Country", StringType))
    .add(StructField("Make", StringType))
  )

  val cameraMessages = (
      sqlContext.readStream
                .option("maxEventsPerTrigger", 1)
                .schema(Schema)
                .parquet("/FileStore/StreamData")
         )
```

Comment: Awesome, Vijay!  This fixed it.  however, I had to specify an extra option (format delta), to indicate it's a delta/streaming table.  Because otherwise, I got the following exception: " The table method is currently only supported for Delta. Please specify Delta with .format("delta")"
So, I have the following code that now works well: 

cameraData.writeStream
 .format("delta")
 .outputMode("append")
 .option("checkpointLocation","/data/events/_checkpoints/data_file")
 .table("cameraMessages")

If you agree, please update your answer, so I can flag it as answered!  Much appreciated.